# Flora Fauna in Vedas

Tags: vedas

The people who promote aryan invasion/migration theory claim that flora and fauna mentioned in vedas don't belong to India , rather belongs to cold climate areas. Please give verses from vedas which talk about flora and fauna .

P.S. please vote to reopen the question , seems like people got confused and voted to close it and labelled it as opinion based whereas I am asking for verses which describe flora and fauna in Vedas

Comment: Talking about climate one has to remember that it changes. Indian climate is not the same as it was during vedic period. For example the Saraswati river does not exist today. Also Himalayas have cold climate.

Comment: Maybe the question is too broad? If you could be specific what exactly you're looking for among flora n fauna in vedas, maybe a certain animal or a plant? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that Vedas do have some Flora which are central asian, a lot of Vedic Geography is placed on the relatively eastern areas of the Rig Veda, a literary analysis of the Rig Veda in the context of internal chronology show a different story.

Comment: Namaste welcome to HSE. While on the site, you can go through the [help centre](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) as well as [Guidelines for new users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). The rules insist on deriving the answer by quoting scriptures or great acharyas. Hope you have a good time on the site :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).